# 301 Redirect appends folder - .htacess

Tags: .htaccess, ubuntu, apache2

I have a .htaccess file in the folder "test".

```
Redirect 301 / http://www.google.at/
```

If I visit the site http://localhost/test/ it redirects me to this link: `www.google.attest`

Why?

Answer (score 0):

You can use to following rule to redirect all traffic to a site without keeping any directory or query strings of the original search:

`RewriteRule (.*) https://www.google.at/? [L,R=301]`